# Logging errors in a new table

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
DECLARE

    v_error_code number;
    v_error_message varchar2(255);
    NO_EDIT STUD.S_NO%TYPE;
BEGIN
    NO_EDIT:=&NO_EDIT;
    DELETE FROM STUD
    WHERE S_NO =NO_EDIT;
    COMMIT;

EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
    ROLLBACK;
    v_error_code := SQLCODE;
    v_error_message := SQLERRM;
    INSERT INTO errors VALUES (v_error_code, v_error_message);
END;
/

CREATE TABLE ERORRS(
    v_error_code number,
    v_error_message varchar2(255)   
);
```

Errors in SQL*Plus

```
ERROR at line 17:
ORA-06550: line 17, column 17:
PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
ORA-06550: line 17, column 5:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
```

Comment: The table has to exist before you refer to it.

Comment: Why don't you change the order of the commands, eg. take `CREATE TABLE` statement to top

Comment: Somewhat ironically you have a spelling error in your `CREATE TABLE` statement. You created a table named `ERORRS` (double R after the O) but are attempting to insert into a table named `ERRORS` (double R before the O).